# $\lim_{x\to0^{+}}xf(x)=0$ if f(x) is integrable and monotonic decreasing.

Tags: calculus, integration, limits, functions, improper-integrals

let $f:(0,1]\to[0,\infty)$ decreasing monotonic function, and the improper integral $\int_{0}^{1}f(x)dx$ converges, how can I show that the $\lim_{x\to0^{+}}xf(x)=0$ I tried using the limit convergence test of improper integrals in order to prove that the limit must be 0, otherwise, we can infer from it that the improper integral $\int_{0}^{1}\frac{1}{x}dx$ does converge, which is untrue. But I can't figure out how to prove that the limit does exist (even in the broad sense), so I can't infer $\lim_{x\to0^{+}}\frac{f(x)}{\frac{1}{x}}$ does exist.

Comment: Try proving the contrapositive: if $f$ is monotonic decreasing and that limit isn't zero, show that $f$ isn't integrable.

Comment: Since $f$ is monotone decreasing, you can construct its inverse $f^{-1}:[0,\infty)\to (0,1]$ and talk instead about the integral $\int_0^\infty f^{-1}(x)\mathrm dx$. If $\lim_{x\to 0^+}xf(x)>0$, what does that say about the behavior of $f^{-1}(x)$ as $x\to\infty$ ?

Comment: The assumption is equivalent to  $\lim_{x\to 0^+}\int\limits_0^xf(t)\,dt =0.$ The integral under the limit sign is greater or equal $xf(x).$ Hence the limit in question is equal $0.$